# Is it possible to limit range when transposing data in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Is it possible to limit range when transposing data in google sheets?
I am trying to Transpose rows of data for printing but the data columns are too long especially if I am transposing 50 rows, I need to limit them to 5 columns then drop down and start at the first column of next row.is this at all possible?

```
[Data Sheet][1]
[Transposed Data Sheet][2]
[Transposed data sheet needed][3]
```

Example Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LfaI4zCjvoQP_aWdKlXlx6QOkTa2LctyHkSpqPuW6MY/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance, 
Johnny

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a clever way to do this automatically. If you don't mind a few copies of the formulas, then you can use `INDIRECT` or `OFFSET` to grab a subset of your selection. eg.

`=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("Data!1:5")` or `=TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(Data!1:21, 0, 0, 5, 10))`

Assuming you have a copy of your formula every 10 rows, you could then use something like `FLOOR(ROW()/10)*5+1` to automatically update the slice of data you are working with for the copies of the formula that you are working with. eg.

`=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("Data!" & FLOOR(ROW()/10)*5+1 & ":" & FLOOR(ROW()/10)*5+5))`

or

`=TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(Data!$1:$21, FLOOR(ROW()/10)*5, 0, 5, 10))`

Answer (score 0):

A way to rearrange a (limited) number of elements is using JOIN() ad subsequently SPLIT(). The limit of JOIN() is 50.000 characters.
This is a single-cell formula.
Here the A1:A15 range is joined and every 5 elementa, a "|" is added, causing a "new line".

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(
    SPLIT(
      TRANSPOSE(
        SPLIT(
          JOIN(",", {A1:A15} & IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A15); 5) = 0, "|", ) ), 
          "|"
        )
      ), 
      ","
    )
  )
```